# How to add audio strip for specific action

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I am making a lightsaber in Blender 2.80. I have rigged it and made 2 actions to go with it already- one for opening and one for closing. I also want to add audio to the animations. I have tried to do so in the video sequencer but I am unable to add audio strips which are specific to a single action.

How can I add an audio strip so that it plays only when a particular action is played?

Comment: Maybe look into the *Speaker* type object

Comment: I had a look at the speaker objects and now I have 2 speakers- one which plays the opening sound and one which plays the closing sound. I know how to choose which frame each speaker starts playing on, but how do I choose which action each speaker plays with?  Is there a way to make the first audio play with the first action only?